# OneToMany relationship doesn't save id of owner entity in secondary entity

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

Im trying to save in postgres 2 entities, ***Configuration*** and ***Screen***. ***Configuration*** can have many ***Screens***, then is `oneToMany`, and one ***Screen*** can have one ***Configuration***, then is`manyToOne`. I'm using `JPA` to save those entities. The problem I have is, in ***Screen*** table, ***configuration_id*** relationship is not saved. That's my code:

```
@Data
public class Configuration  {

@Id
private String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "id_configuration", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Screen> screen;
```

And this other

```
@Table
@Entity
@Data
public class Screen {

private String status;

@JoinColumn(name = "configuration_id")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Configuration configuration;
```

when I create a new ***Configuration***, I indicate the ***Screen*** that should be created except the 'id' field (it's configuration id created randomlly)

The data is saved well, both in ***Configuration*** and ***Screen***, except for that (***id_configuration***) field. There is a ***configuration_id*** field in ***Screen*** table, but it is always empty and never filled. Why is this happening? I'm indicating the cascade type ALL, and relationships are well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Due to tutorials like: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

I guess the problem in your model is `mappedBy` in `@OneToMany`. In your case it should point to class field which mapping this relation.

So it should be: `@OneToMany(mapped_by = "configuration", ...)`

Comment: That's not the problem. I changed it @OneToMany(mapped_by = "configuration"....) but still the id is not saved in database

Comment: It is A problem. You have a few apparently. Next is - do your screens really have a configuration set? If it is null, the foreign key "configuration_id" will be null.